# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'IDNumber' was corrupted

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h> 

using namespace std;

struct MyID
{
    char FirstName[10]; // array for lenight of the word.
    char LastName[10]; // array for lenight of the word.
    int IdNumber;
};

void InitializeArray(MyID IDNumber[], int Size);
//void SortTheArray(MyID IDNumber[], int Size);
int main(){
    const int Size = 100;
    MyID IDNumber[Size];

    strcpy_s(IDNumber[Size].FirstName, "Aziz");
    strcpy_s(IDNumber[Size].LastName, "LEGEND");
    // I believe the error is around here. 

    InitializeArray(IDNumber, Size);
    //SortTheArray(IDNumber, Size);
}

void InitializeArray(MyID IDNumber[], int Size){

    //srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
        //IDNumber[i].IdNumber = rand() %100 ;

        cout<<IDNumber[i].FirstName<<endl;
        IDNumber[i].LastName;
    }
}
```

[image]

I have this problem, every time I want to test my function and struct, this error will prompt. Also, I want to  see if my name will print correctly before continue to write rest program. The idea is I want to print same name every time without ask user to print name every time. 
Also, I have upload the picture of result if you want to see it.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are two separate languages.  For example, the C++ language has the `std::string` type for text.  The C language only has character arrays (which are prone to **buffer overrun** errors).

Comment: This C++ Language. Thank you

Comment: Remove the C language tag.

Comment: looks like c to me : |

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` instead of character arrays.  Prefer to use `std::vector` instead of arrays.

Comment: `strcpy_s(IDNumber[Size].FirstName, "Aziz");`,  you are accessing an array out of bounds here.

Comment: I removed the tag, sorry for that.

Comment: felix< yeah, i tried to change array, or write without array. it gave me same error. it should be without array Right?

Comment: Thomas<< i will try to use string at this time, and i will see if it works. thank you.

Comment: @user7066458 Can't tell, it depends. Looks like you want to give every `MyID` in the array a firstname and a lastname. Then you should do this in a loop, and be careful with the bound. If you just want to initialize the last element of the array, you can try `IDNumber[Size-1]`.

Comment: @felix Thank you, but same result, you can see a picture "enter image description here"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using arrays, you are experiencing **buffer overrun** error:

```
const int Size = 100;
MyID IDNumber[Size];

strcpy_s(IDNumber[Size].FirstName, "Aziz");
strcpy_s(IDNumber[Size].LastName, "LEGEND");
```

The expression `IDNumber[Size]` is equivalent to `IDNumber[100]`.

In C++, array slot indices go from `0` to `Size - 1`.  You are accessing one past the end of the array.

**Edit 1: Initializing an array**
Based on your comment, you can use a loop to initialize the slots in an array (vector):

```
struct Person
{
  std::string first_name;
  std::string last_name;
};

const unsigned int CAPACITY = 100;

int main()
{
  std::vector<Person> database(CAPACITY);
  Person p;
  std::ostringstream name_stream;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; ++i)
  {
    name_stream << "Aziz" << i;
    database[i].first_name = name_stream.str();
    database[i].last_name = "LEGEND";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried this but didnt work. Thank you, but the idea i want to copy same name eveytime. For Exampe, Aziz001, Aziz002, Aziz003, ......... Aziz100. like this and i dont have to ask user to enter their name eveytime.

Comment: To assign each element, you will need a loop.